# revive ad server folder not writable

Tags: php, apache, advertisement-server

I am trying to install Revive Ad Server on my Centos 7. I installed apache, php, mysql. Now, I tried to set proper permissions to my directories like below:

[image]

As we can see, the var directory is fully writable and readable. However, when we execute the installation, it says the directory is not writable. Any step we are missing?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

use recommended permissions for revive ad server.

```
 a+w $REVIVE_INSTALLATION_DIR/var
 a+w $REVIVE_INSTALLATION_DIR/plugins
 a+w $REVIVE_INSTALLATION_DIR/www/admin/plugins
 a+w $REVIVE_INSTALLATION_DIR/images
```